# Uploading and receiving json data and file in python3 via postman

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i was a bit curious about how can i send json data and files via postman and receive the json data and the same file in my flask application.

> Is there an convenient way to send files or shall i save the file in
> another route and generate an url and pass it in the request json. Or
> shall i directly send the file and save it in my server file system ?
> if i do so ,can i fetch the file from the server ?

[image]

i would appreciate any help.

Code :

```
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):

        # keys = request.json.keys()
        dat = request.form['request']
        file_path = request.files['file_path']

        file_path.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(file_path.filename)))
        # create the folders when setting up your app
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'htmlfi'), exist_ok=True)

        # when saving the file
        file_path.save(os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'htmlfi', secure_filename(file_path.filename)))
        print(dat)
        # company_id =flask_praetorian.current_user().company_id
        # data = dict(request.json)
        # print(data)
        return "done"
api.add_resource(Test,'/Test_data')
```

I am able to get the data ,but it is not json but manageable. but is it an efficient way to send file directly and save it in file system or is it better to use google cloud storage as i am using gcp? i was think about server load.

Also it is hectic to check for valid keys ,
e.g i have to

```
if "keys" not in request.json.keys():
```

which makes my work easier, but in the form data approach , i have to check like request.form['request'][0] for id key and as such

Answer (score 0):

You can send your data at your python code, you dont have to send .json file to your server. If you are using dictionary data type, convert it to json and send your server in your request’s body. You will see the data at postman. If you want to save that as a json file, maybe you can get the data and do that at your server side.

Comment: i am going to receive the json data from client side , and it is much easier to validate a json data rather than a text data.

Comment: You can convert the data to json at client side too